# Calculate maturity of an annuity-loan with one formula in a cell without helper table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Excel**

```
   |      A          |     B    |    C   |    D   |      E    |       F     |     G   |     H    |  
---|-----------------|----------|--------|--------|-----------|-------------|---------|----------|---
1  |  Loan           |  50.000  |  Year  |  Start | Interests |  Repayment  | Annuity |    End   |
2  |  Interests p.a. |      2%  |    1   | 50.000 |   -1.250  |    -1.750   | -3.000  |   48.250 |
3  |  Annuity p.a.   |   3.000  |    2   | 48.250 |   -1.206  |    -1.794   | -3.000  |   46.456 |
4  |  Maturity       |      ??  |    3   | 46.456 |   -1.161  |    -1.839   | -3.000  |   44.618 |
5  |                 |          |    4   | 44.618 |   -1.115  |    -1.885   | -3.000  |   42.733 |
   |                 |          |        |        |           |             |         |          |
   |                 |          |        |        |           |             |         |          |
21 |                 |          |    20  |  8.094 |     -202  |    -2.798   | -3.000  |    5.297 |
22 |                 |          |    21  |  5.297 |     -132  |    -2.868   | -3.000  |    2.429 |
23 |                 |          |    22  |  2.429 |      -61  |    -2.939   | -3.000  |        0 |
```

---

The above loan of `50.000` has an interest rate of `2%` and an annuity of `3.000`. 
In the table from `C1:H23` the annual development of the remaining loan is displayed.

Based on this `helper table` I know that the maturity of the loan is `22` years by using the following formula in `Cell B4`:

```
B4 = COUNTA(C1:C22)
```

However, my question is if there is an Excel-Formula that can calculate the maturity **in one cell** so I do not need the `helper table` in `C1:H23`?

Comment: Have you checked functions like cumipmt(0 or cumprinc() or IRR() or PPMT() etc?

Comment: Try using `NPER()` which is used to calculate payment periods for loan!

Comment: Your table above seems to show 2.5% interest rate. If you apply @MayukhBhattacharya's NPER recommendation with 2.5% interest, you will arrive at 21.83 years.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick Sir, absolutely correct, and with 2.0% it arrives at 20.248 years